# database credential security - store in PHP or pass via post?

Tags: php, html, mysql, security

I'm wondering about best practices here.
I've got a few php scripts that are contained in a password protected folder on my server. 
In those php scripts I include the login credentials for the database (mySQL).
I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it or should I be passing these credentials to the php script via post?
My server is under a shared SSL, so data sent via post is supposedly quite secure.
Does anyone have info / opinions on this?
Thanks!!

Comment: store them in the script, unless you're worried someone can access the script contents. otherwise you're letting those passwords float across the wire, and all it takes is for one mistaken NON-ssl hit and you're compromised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to not store it where it can be accessed through the web server.

If, for instance, you have a folder structure like this:

```
code/
    www-root/
        some-folder/
        another-folder/
        index.php
```

it would make sense to make another folder within code where you can store the file. That way, nobody who hasn't got server access can find it. Example:

```
code/
    sensitive/
        mysql_credentials.php
    www-root/
        some-folder/
        another-folder/
        index.php
```

Comment: Thanks, Joel. That sounds about like what I'm doing. None of these scripts are available to the web server and are for an app I'm making.

Comment: (not sure why this site cut me off..)
I store all of them in a password protected folder.
I think it is the same as you mean (I have very little experience with servers). The directory structure is like this:<br>  
/ (Current Folder)<br>  access-logs<br>  etc<br>  html_sec <-- password protected all php scripts here<br>  mail<br>  public_ftp<br>  public_html <-- I imagine is the document root / www-root<br>  tmp<br>  www <--- appears to be a mirror of public_html<br>  I kind of like Garbage's answer too. What do you think of it?

Comment: Password protection is great, too! I agree that you seem to be doing exactly what I suggested. When somebody goes to your site, they will never be able to access any of the folders that aren't public_html/www (through web server) or public_ftp (which is likely empty anyway) - assuming the server has been set up correctly, of course. Adding a layer of password protection may be unnecessary, but hey, better safe than sorry. :) I think Garbage's solution is also good, but moving sensitive information to where it can never be accessed in the first place I believe is even better. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this, I would create a separate file (say `config.ini`) to store database credentials and

1. Store it in non-public folder.
2. Create a rule in web server to NOT serve files with .ini extensions
3. Create [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file if required.

My PHP script will read credentials from this file and use it.